# Error while loading sample data in DocDoku

Tags: java

So, I've compiled all submodules from https://github.com/docdoku/docdoku-plm and then used the ./loadSample.sh script from https://github.com/docdoku/docdoku-plm-sample-data/tree/7a6b3e158d66dfa4c94645943c24c70a22e645b8 to load the sample data and I always end by getting this error:

```
[INFO] - Starting load process... 
[INFO] - Checking server availability...
[SEVERE] - Ooops, something went wrong while loading sample data : Not Found
Not Foundcom.docdoku.plm.api.client.ApiException: Not Found
    at com.docdoku.plm.api.client.ApiClient.handleResponse(ApiClient.java:838)
    at com.docdoku.plm.api.client.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:773)
    at com.docdoku.plm.api.services.LanguagesApi.getLanguagesWithHttpInfo(LanguagesApi.java:106)
    at com.docdoku.plm.api.services.LanguagesApi.getLanguages(LanguagesApi.java:93)
    at com.docdoku.loaders.SampleLoader.checkServerAvailability(SampleLoader.java:132)
    at com.docdoku.loaders.SampleLoader.load(SampleLoader.java:77)
    at com.docdoku.loaders.Main.main(Main.java:73)
```

Every build was successful and I don't really know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have the same problem.
I found that the URL was incomplete in the sample script.

You need to append a prefix to the path. like this
http://localhost:8080/docdoku-plm-server-rest

Run loadSample.sh or loadSample.bat depending on your OS

```
    ./loadSample.sh -u login -p password -h url [-w workspaceId]  
    
Parameters :

* login : your account name (will be created) - required
* password : your account password (will be created) - required
* url : url of the DocDokuPLM instance server (http://localhost:8080/docdoku-plm-server-rest) - required
* workspaceId : then name of the workspace to be created - optional, will be generated if not specified
```